# Rotate circle and position arc over it with start and end angle

Tags: svg, geometry

Hi is there any way to design the below picture with SVG or any other way?

[image: SVG Image]

Please find the SVG Code for the circle with head

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="110px" height="110px" viewBox="0 0 110 110" enable-background="new 0 0 110 110" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
<title>Sample</title>
<g>
    <path d="M60.391,23.712V0H48.975v23.571c-21.802,2.619-37.87,20.953-37.87,43.041c0,23.995,19.536,43.391,43.411,43.391
        c23.855,0,43.392-19.396,43.392-43.391C97.907,44.736,81.202,26.543,60.391,23.712z M22.501,66.682
        c0-17.628,14.369-31.998,32.015-31.998c17.626,0,31.995,14.37,31.995,31.998c0,17.625-14.299,32.065-31.995,32.065
        C36.8,98.747,22.501,84.307,22.501,66.682z"/>
</g>
```

**Head**
Based on the head angle in the example 332° the circle should rotate

**Red Arc** 
Based on the start and end position of the arc it should start from there with displaying the start and end position as in the picture 50 and 180.

Please help me to design :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this i used `rect` and `circle` instead of `path`

```css
svg{
    background:#223D50;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect x="40" y="30" width="3" height="12" fill="grey" transform="rotate(-28 42 50)"/>
    <circle cx="42" cy="53" r="10" stroke-width="3" stroke="grey" fill="none"/>
    <circle cx="42" cy="53" r="18" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5" stroke="red" stroke-dasharray="36.11111% 100%" stroke-dashoffset="0" transform="rotate(-30 42, 53)"/>
    <text x="36" y="55" fill="white" font-size="5">Check</text>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Akshay, But can you please tell me how this will work dynamically, like changing with angle will point to the exact degrees. For example in my attached image the angle 50 and 180 points to the exact angle of that image. Please suggest me.

Comment: @VinothKumar 332 angle is created by rotating the rect by  -28 degree (360- 28 = 332)  the red part is 36.111% of a circle (130*100/360)

Comment: @Akshya, Thanks for your reply, is there any way to place the text 50 and 180 as like as in image? even if the angle of arc moves, it should show the respective position.

Comment: @VinothKumar How does the angle move like click type or something ?

Comment: on page load the value will be placed via AngularJS from server side

Comment: @VinothKumar The rotation of the rect is decided by this code `rotate(-28 42 50)` change `-28` to the value you get or if that doesn't work wrap the elements in a `g` and rotate it the percentage value is determined by the `stroke-dashoffset` change it's value accordingly